# Hosting a WebService/WCF on Windows Mobile Device?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm interessted in writing an application that is running on windows mobile. I've allready a winform application that is hosting an WCF service. I wan't to port the application to windows mobile (6.0) and up. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397842.aspx) is hosting an article about WCF on Compact Framework, but it says hosting is not an option yet.

Do i have to write it all by my self over a TCP Listener?

Bye Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes; you'd need to do a lot of this yourself using `TcpListener`. Even `HttpListener` isn't in Compact Framework, which is a shame (otherwise it would be easy).

There may be pre-canned solutions available, however.

For interest, I have an open-source framework that is *nearly* there - it has all the serialization / dispatch / etc code, but I haven't yet added raw `TcpListener` support, which is a shame. But maybe soon.

Comment: You sir, are a sick sick puppy :)

Comment: Hi,

sorry but as fare as i can see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

TCPListener is supported on compact framework? Am i missing something?

Bye Marco

Comment: @Marco - nobody said it wasn't... I said that HttpListener wasn't available (which it isn't).

Comment: @Marc: now i get it... didn't realize i talked about tcp and you about http... and yes it's a shame...

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you port the mono HttpListener class to the Compact Framework.  At least you'd be starting with a pretty well tested code base and as baseline.

Comment: thanx for the reply but the project never got kicked out of planing, so i didn't take it any further. your answer is a valid point and i will mark it as an answer.